# Intellij Idea side panel graphic glitch

Tags: intellij

I'm always getting this annoying glitch with IntelliJ Idea 14.1.5 on Ubuntu 15.10:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: This happening always ?

Comment: This happens after I use the editor for a while. I didn't manage to find out what precisely triggers it

Comment: It started with the upgrade from 15.04 to 15.10

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this installing the last 1.8 Oracle JDK intead of openjdk-8